# Formal translation of this statement.

Tags: elementary-set-theory, predicate-logic

I've been working hours on translating this one statement into formal mathematical language:

- If $\textit{f}$ is a continuous on the interval $[\textit{a},\textit{b}]$ and differentiable on $(\textit{a},\textit{b})$, then there is a number $\textit{c}$ $\in$ $(\textit{a},\textit{b})$ for which $\textit{f}^\prime(\textit{c}) = \tfrac{f(b)-f(a)}{b-a}$.

What I have come up with are (these are my best versions):

---

- Informally,

$\forall$ func. $f : \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$, ($f$ continuous and differentiable) iff $\exists$ $a,b$ $\in$ $\mathbb{R}$ s.t. $f$ continuous on $[a,b]$ and $f$ differentiable on $(a,b)$ $\implies$ $\exists c \in  (a,b)$ s.t. $\textit{f}^\prime(\textit{c}) = \tfrac{f(b)-f(a)}{b-a}$.

---

- Formally,

($\forall f$)(

[($f: \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$) & (($f$ cont.) & ($f$ diff.))] $\iff$ (

($\exists a,b$)([$a,b \in \mathbb{R}$] & [[($f$ cont. on $[a,b]$) & ($f$ diff. on $(a,b)$)] $\implies$ [($\exists c)([c \in  (a,b)$] & ($\textit{f}^\prime(\textit{c}) = \tfrac{f(b)-f(a)}{b-a}$))]

]))).

---

I'm not at all confident with what I'm doing.

Comment: I don't see any "if and only if" in the original statement.

Comment: $\forall_{a,b\in\mathbb{R}, a<b} \;\forall_{f:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}, f\in C\left([a,b]\right), f\in diff\left((a,b)\right)} \;\exists_{c\in(a,b)} \;f'(c) = \frac{f(b)-f(a)}{b-a}$

Comment: ($\forall b$)([($b \in \mathbb{R}$) & ($a < b$)] $\implies$(

($\forall f$)([$f$ func.] $\implies$ [$\big($($f$ cont.  on $[a,b]$) & ($f$ diff. on $(a,b)$)$\big)$ $\implies$ (

($\exists c$)([$c \in (a,b)$]) & [$f^\prime$(c) $= \frac{f(b) - f(a)}{b - a}$]

))])))))

Comment: As differentiable implies continuous, the orginal statement should be simplified.